# How to get a tweet's retweeters using twitter api and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I am trying to get a tweet's retweeters from the Twitter API using node.js
but it does not work.

Here is my code:

```
var twit = require("twit");

var Twitter = new twit({

    consumer_key: 'XXXX',

    consumer_secret: 'XXXX',

    access_token: 'XXXX',

    access_token_secret: 'XXXX',

    timeout_ms: 60 * 1000,

    strictSSL: true, 

});

var getRtweeters = function () {

    var params = {

        id: 1188469454260330497,

        count: 5,

    }

    console.log("basliyor");

    Twitter.get('statuses/retweeters/ids', params, function (err, data) {

        if (err) {

            console.log("error", err);

        }

        else {

            console.log("cekilen data", data.retweeters[0]);
        }

    });
};

getRtweeters();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like the Tweet you were trying to investigate has been deleted, so it's impossible to check this now. However, the issue in your code here is that you need to send the Tweet ID as a string, not as an integer. So, for example:

```js
    var params = {
        id: '1174361480734466048', // this Tweet does exist
        count: 5,
    }
```

Also, `data.retweeters[0]` is not a valid field. Try just logging out `data` instead. Or, if you just want the first result, try `data.ids[0]`.